# How to call Method from in Kotlin?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a two files `one.kt and two.kt`, i have innerclass in one.kt file. i want to call the that innner class when some action performed like button click in `Two.kt` file. I tried some of ways but the `innerclass` or method does not call. please guide me what i had mistakes. The One.kt file call from `manifest` file.
like this,

```
<application
        android:name="com.abc.cde.One"
```

**One.kt**

```
open class One : MultiDexApplication(), KodeinAware {
    ---------------
    --------------
    OnCreate()
    ---------------
    ---------------

inner class CallmyClass() {

        fun CallMyMethod(i: Int) :Module {

            return Module {
                bind<ExchangeRateProvider>() with singleton { CryptoCompareExchangeProvider(this@One, instance()) }
                bind<SyncProgressProvider>() with singleton { SyncProgressProvider() }
                bind<WallethKeyStore>() with singleton { keyStore }
                bind<Settings>() with singleton { KotprefSettings }

                bind<CurrentTokenProvider>() with singleton { CurrentTokenProvider(instance()) }

                bind<AppDatabase>() with singleton { Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "maindb").build() }
                bind<NetworkDefinitionProvider>() with singleton { NetworkDefinitionProvider(instance()) }
                //bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext) }
                bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) }

                bind<FourByteDirectory>() with singleton { FourByteDirectoryImpl(instance(), applicationContext) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Two.kt**

```
class Two : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {

    -----------
    -----------
    -----------

    oncreate()

    -------------
    --------------

     val dd = One().CallmyClass().CallMyMethod(1)
}
```

**Note: Important Note One.kt called from Manifest file in Application tag.**

**UPDATE**

**How to Call fun CallMyMethod(i: Int) :Module { ......} from Two.kt. Now inner class called but the method not called**

Comment: You cannot call `One()` since it is only the name of a file, not the name of some class defined in that file from what I see. Is this your actual code or did you make some name changes before posting it here?

Comment: sorry, Now update  my question . i just rename the file names for posting , for better understanding . both are classes @flyx

Comment: Okay, looks reasonable now. What's the error message?

Comment: No error, but class not called .  @flyx

Comment: it just skip that block and excute other codes

Comment: try `(application as One).CallmyClass().CallMyMethod(1)`

Comment: tried . . . class not called @Bal0r

Comment: maybe the problem occurs when returning the module. I see you have a lot of dependencies in that return statement, have you tried debugging them, to see if they don't break something, maybe a null somewhere that causes the whole statement to get skipped?

Comment: no null values when i debugging my app. and also break not stop because of innerclass not called. its fully skipped

Comment: If you stop at a breakpoint on the code in `Two`, then force step into it, where do you land? It has to call *something*.

Comment: hi @flyx, now class is called but bind the data override error is arrived